# Angular: Run method every time a directive updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking to have a function run every time an angular directive updates. In my case, I have an array of modal configurations that get used on a modal markup template. 
Every time the template is used to generate a modal due to a change in the model, I want to run a positionModal() method. 
scope.$watch in the link function doesn't seem to notice when I change the model, and I cant think of any other way of doing this. I tried a post-link function thinking that the compile function would get called when the directive was applied, but that doesn't seem to work either. Here is my example controller:

```
MyApp.controller("ModalController", function () {

    //Define scope vars
    $scope.modals = [];

    $scope.$on("modalTrigger", function (event, settings) {
        $scope.modals.push(settings);
    });
});
```

Note: I've simplified the controller here- know that it DOES work.

Here is the template code:

```
<div class="modalParent" ng-controller="ModalController">
    <div id="{{modal.id}}" class="modal" ng-class="modal.type" ng-repeat="modal in modals">
        <div class="content">
            <h2 ng-show="modal.title">{{modal.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{modal.message}}</p>
            <button>{{modal.button}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive is currently like this:

```
MyApp.directive("modalParent", function () {
    var positionModals = function (element) {
        element.find(".modal .content").each(function () {
            //position logic here
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "C",
        compile: function (tElement) {
            positionModals(tElement);
        }
    };
});
```

Note: Also simplified for the purposes here.
The positionModals() call works when the first modal gets pushed to the array. After that, it stops working.

I've tried using the linking function as well, same result. scope.$watch(modals, function(){...}) does not work.

Can somebody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you try to do scope.watch and how does your html structure look like? i.e the relationship between `ModalController` and `modal-parent`?

Comment: ng-controller="ModalController" for the div with class of modalParent. scope.$watch was placed in the link function

Comment: Nothing here is connected enough. Can you replicate in a simple demo?

Comment: Let me provide the template (should have done that before)

Comment: Okay, modified the original description. Controller is applied to modalParent, directive should run against the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!
I was applying the directive to the parent, ".modalParent".
The ng-repeated element in this case is the modal itself ".modal".
You would want the directive to run on elements that get updates as the model changes, because then the linking function will get called each time the element is instantiated, rather than sitting and watching the parent and trying to update from there.
Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling like this, my approach is to write this in the services and inject that services in the controller wherever you want to get that function or the data to be notified as,

Services.js

```
as.service("xyzservice",function(factoryname){
//here the code goes...
})
```

Now inject in Controller,

```
ac.controller("controllername",function(xyzservice){

})
ac.controller("controllername",function(servicename){

})

ac.controller("controllername",function(xyzservice){

})
```

Here we have injected it in the two controller, we can get it.